# Same file descriptor at /dev/ttyACM0 and /dev/ttyACM1

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, debian, usb, file-descriptor

I'm trying to read data from 2 gps receiver using a RasPI. I start 2 programs in 2 different shell. One program must read the ttyACM0 and the other one the ttyACM1.

Unlucky i get the same file descriptor for both port (fd = 7) even if i start the second program after the first (so it should get the fd = 8 but it doesent happen).

Do u know why they get the same f.d.? 
Do I have to put all the read programs in one? (i checked it and if i open the usb ports in only one program i get acm0 fd =7 and acm1 fd =8)

Prog. 1:

```
//Open the file with name saved in char* port0
pUSB0  = fopen(port0, "r+");                                                        // r+ = read and write 
if (pUSB0 == NULL) perror ("Error opening USB0\n");
// Get the file descriptor
fdpUSB0 = fileno(pUSB0);
if (fdpUSB0 < 0 ){
    fprintf(stdout, "Can't get the File Descriptor of %s\n", port0);
    fprintf(stdout, "Error: %s", strerror(errno));
}
fprintf(stdout, "The file descriptor's port0 %s is fd = %d\n", port0, fdpUSB0);
```

Prog. 2:

same as 1 but with port1= /dev/ttyACM1;

Comment: Why fopen, what made you to prefer fopen over open()?

Comment: Why not?
I used fopen just because it works. I didnt think about technical issues.

fopen calls open, it shouldnt change that much.

If i do a single program and i do fopen(ttyacm0) & fopen(ttyacm1) it works well without f.d. problems.

Maybe if i use fopen in 2 different program it "doesnt see" the other fopen calls?

Comment: I can suggest to have a function something like `int device_open(char *device) { /*Open the device, make sure you return the fd*/}` and then you can use that function whenever you want to open the serial device and you can close them once your done with it.

Comment: They are two different programs, so the same fd can refer to different  devices. If I start 2 Terminals and do `echo Hi` in each, the output will occur in 2 different terminals but both `echo` programs wrote to fd 1.

Comment: Yeah the data are different so it is working correctly but.. wow i lost 1day just bcause i thought it was an error :S 

Thanks all!